# Multiple servlets on multiple ports in jetty

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jetty-9

I want to serve two servlets on different port, something like

```
http://localhost:8888/servlet1
http://localhost:9999/servlet2
```

These servlets are part of one war file. I found a way to do as explained [in this blog.](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/02/16/using-different-context-handlers-on-different-ports-in-jetty-9/)  But I am not using embedded jetty. In my case its a separate jetty installation. I dump my application war file inside webapp directory of jetty. I have configured servlet mappings in web.xml file, which is inside war. I have followed the [jetty documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-virtual-hosts.html) to create connector and virtual hosts by configuring xml files as described there. But still I am not able to understand how/where would I pass in the configuration saying serve servlet1 from 8888 and servlet2 from 9999. Anyone has done this before through xml files?

Comment: There is no such setting in plain war application. Port is part of web container which is separate from application war.

Comment: The entire webapp is served from the defined servlet context path (which seems to be `/` in your case), you cannot split individual parts of a webapp up like that.  This is also messy from a ServletContext, security, sessions, and cors point of view too.  Any solution you wind up with will likely have your original webapp split, or duplicated.